# Aprovar comentários no wordpress através de e-mail

Tags: wordpress, comentários

Estou desenvolvendo um site em Wordpress e tenho a necessidade de que a aprovação dos comentários nos posts seja feita através de e-mail. Procurei plugins e tutoriais sobre o assunto mas não encontrei nada.

A intensão é que o cliente receba o comentário via email no seu smarthphone e tenha 2 links, um para APROVAR e outro para REJEITAR e essa operação seja feita sem a necessidade de logar no site, somente clicando no link.

Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar hook em [`wp_insert_comment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_comment) para ser notificado cada vez que um novo commentário for adicionado ao sistema e enviar o e-mail para o administrador do site com os links "aprovar", "reprovar" e "spam".

Para verificar se o link atual é o de "aprovar" comentário, basta adicionar um hook em `init` e então verificar o link e atualizar o status do comentário.

Para pegar o comentário pelo ID você pode usar a função [`get_comment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment) e para atualizá-lo a função [`wp_update_comment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_comment).

Exemplo:

```
<?php

add_action('wp_insert_comment','comment_inserted');
function comment_inserted($comment_id, $comment_object) {
    // aqui você monta os links e envia o email para o admin (usando as informações em comment_object)
    // ex.: 
    // http://site.com?comment_id=123&approved=1
    // $approved = [0 = reprovar, 1 = aprovar, spam = marcar como spam]
}

add_action('init', '_update_comment');
function _update_comment() {
    if(!isset($_GET['comment_id'] && !isset($_GET['approved'])) {
        // nenhum dos parametros na URL significa que não é o link esperado
        return;
    }

    if(!is_user_logged_in() || !is_admin()) {
        auth_redirect();
        return;
    }

    $comment_id = (int)$_GET['comment_id'];
    $approved = (int)$_GET['approved'];

    $comment = get_comment($comment_id, ARRAY_A);

    // comentário existe e o usuário é admin?
    if($comment !== null is_admin()) {
        // modifica o status de aprovado do comentário dependendo do valor passado
        switch($approved) {
            case '0':
                $comment['comment_approved'] = 0; // 0 = reprovado
                break;
            case '1':
                $comment['comment_approved'] = 1; // 1 = aprovado
                break;

            case 'spam':
                $comment['comment_approved'] = 'spam'; // spam = spam
                break;

            default: // opção inválida. você pode adicionar alugma mensagem de erro aqui;
                return;
                break;
        }

        wp_update_comment($comment); // atualiza o comentário
    }

    // se chegou aqui é porque o comentário foi atualizado.
    // aqui você pode redirecionar o usuário para uma página de sucesso ou fazer qualquer outra coisa.
}
```

<sub>Nota: Acabei de digitar todo este código e não testei, porém ele serve como base para você construir um plugin com estas funcionalidades.</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda André
Vou estudar o código durante o dia de hoje e depois posto o resultado, mas agora já tenho um norte, um por onde começar e por onde seguir, o que torna a solução bem mais fácil.
Novamente, obrigado!

Comment: o código sugerido pelo @andré-ribeiro funcionou?